# Disabling antialias rendering for a label

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, antialiasing

I have a C# Winform application and on my form I have a Label control. Is there a way I can disable antialiasing rendering just for that label? I am using a barcode font and the antialiasing on the black and white font is adding color to the font.